# Algorithm to get permutation from an index from the hypothetical list of all combinations?

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

here is what I mean:

Assuming we have ***X*** number of colours and a 4x4 grid of 16 squares, we can colour **any** of the squares with **any** colour.

Assuming you can generate a list of all possible configurations and the algorithm spits them out one after another(`configuration#1`, then `configuration#2` and so on), is there a way to use a number `i` and get `configuration#i` right off the bat?

(since storing *1e+16* configurations is not possible on normal hardware)

And more importantly, is it possible to have an inverse of this algorithm and to instead give it a configuration, for which it will return an `i` that when plugged back in will return the original configuration? Something like this:

```
int colours[4][4] = GenerateSomeConfig(); // Gets some combination of colours
int i = GetIndex(colours); // This is the main function I was asking about
int colours2[4][4] = GetConfig(i); // This is the reverse of GetIndex()

assert(CompareGridsEqual(colours, colours2)); // This shouldn't break
```

Comment: Since you ask whether it is possible the answer is simple: yes, it is.

Comment: Without a strict order of how that list of permutations are going to look like, who knows which permutation comes after which? Without a specified order any permutation could be i.

Comment: @hynner could you direct me to an algorithm that does this(if there is such already preset) please?

Comment: Note that with `uint32_t`, you may use at most 4 colours. (and 16 colours for uint64_t).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are combinations with repetition.

Anyways. Let's simplify problem just a little bit. Let us say we have 10 colours. Numbered 0 to 9. Lets also number our squares, from 1 to 16 (or whatever. You say 4x4, your code says 16x16 but it's not important).

You can use the number of the color of the box. So you would end up with lets say:

```
0 9 6 3 
4 7 5 1 
0 2 1 7 
5 2 3 4
```

Now you can take the grid, and make it a stripe - `0 9 6 3 4 7 5 1 0 2 1 7 5 2 3 4`.  Remove spaces and you have your mapping.

To use different number of colors, use different base. Different size of grid will result in different number of digits in the encoded number.

You should be able to take off from this hint. I'm not going to write a c++ implementation to match your effort =P, and I think you should be able to do it. The only technical difficulty is to deal with numbers of arbitrary base.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, it is possible for every algorithm that generates the configurations to create a wrapper that converts a configuration to integer and vice versa.

The simplest and general solution would be like this:

```
config_t GetConfig(size_t index)
{
    Generator gen;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i) gen.GetNextConfig();
    return gen.GetNextConfig();
}


size_t GetIndex(const config_t & conf)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    Generator gen;
    while(gen.GetNext() != conf) ++ret;
    return ret;
}
```

This is obviously not very efficient way of doing it, but it shows that it's possible. If you need to do it more efficiently you'll probably have to sacrifice generality and implement it specifically for the one generator. @luk32's answer shows you the way of doing it for a very simple generator, but of course there can be more complex generators.

Comment: Yeah I could possibly jump around a loop and check for similarity of the config generated from the current number to the config generated by the number I'm given and depending on if the similarity is increasing as I loop forward I can modify the index of the loop, for instance if it's decreasing when it had previously increased, I have passed trough the right config and I roll back the loop a bit.

Comment: @shortage_radeon: I'm not sure I understand. It sounds to me like you're talking about some sort of binary search in the ordered sequence of all possible configurations. But I don't really see how you would (efficiently) measure the similarity of 2 configurations without the knowledge of the algorithm being used for the generator.

Comment: Well I can compare how many of the 16 squares from one config match the 16 from another. BTW there will be an identical generator on both the sender and receiver of the number value, so it would be known for sure by both. The entire hypothetical array would be 5960464477 gigabytes, so I think going trough it in a loop won't work reallistically. I can't get my head around how else it could be done tho.

Comment: @shortage_radeon: As I said, if you want it to be more efficient you'll probably have to optimize for the specific generator. luk32 shows you an example for a simple generator.